# Spring Boot 2.0.2 - Missing classes MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration, MetricFilterAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

in Spring Boot 1.5 application the application class was annotated with:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
```

These classes were I believe in the package:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.*;
```

Now upgrade to Spring Boot 2.0.2 but those classes are missing, can't find them anywhere.

What changed? How to solve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spring Boot’s own metrics have been replaced with support, **including
>   auto-configuration**, for Micrometer and dimensional metrics.

if you want to disable metrics set `management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=false`

there is a complete guide that makes migration a lot easier 
[Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide)

Comment: Interestingly, if search for "Spring Boot 2.0 MetricFilterAutoConfiguration", I get a result: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html?org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.html

If I search for "Spring Boot 2.0.2 MetricFilterAutoConfiguration" no result. If I replace in above URL "...2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/..." it is not there, it must have disappeared above version Spring Boot 2.0, perhaps from 2.0.1 or 2.0.2 on.

You suggest, to set the property in the application.yml file? Could I use still an annotation?

Comment: there is org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration & MetricsAutoConfiguration, but I don't now the effect when you  exculde these configurations

Comment: And you have org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.simple.SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration. (Auto-configured after all other MeterRegistry beans and only used as a fallback.)